# Add a timer to the rate-limiting messages for asking questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, asking-questions, rate-limiting

I'm getting this message:

> You can only ask 6 questions in a 24-hour period

Could you add a timer, so that I know how much time I have to wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your [activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1544337/camil-staps?tab=activity&sort=posts) (filtered by post) instead.

It tell you how long ago you asked your questions.

Ask yourself, how often do you think people would run into this limit? I don't think we want to encourage people flooding the site with questions. In any case, this is *not* going to be a frequent occurrence.

Comment: Yeah, of course, but a timer would be easier :)

Comment: A timer takes developer effort, what does it add to the site to justify that effort?

Comment: Not so much developer effort... but I get your point.

Comment: I don't think the limit is meant to be reached often.For the few times a user reaches the limit, you can use Martijn's approach and look at the activity tab. If you reach the limit too often, maybe you don't search enough before asking.